# Muscle tone and default heart rate - psychological conclusions?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, reference-request, physiology

I know that muscle tension and heart rate goes up as we get stressed, but what if in normal conditions some have a lower heart rate and muscle tension while others higher?

Does this say something about brain configuration? Temperament maybe? Do sanguine people have lower such stats than say choleric people? I have seen that similar people have same stats, in this case high stats people are always static characters (they don't change easily), have strong personalities, and are workaholics... etc.

I am pretty sure there's a study on this, I was wondering if anyone has any idea as to where to find it.

Comment: Your first question can be answered with "Statistics."  A carefully designed experiment would account for as many confounding factors as possible.

Comment: And yes, you're in the right place! :)